# In Grails is there something in domain class like onLoad()?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Guys,

I have a following domain class:

```
class Product { 
    String name, 
    String productRecord,

    static transients = ['productRecord']
}
```

productRecord is a field which is generated automatically based on the id of the Product instance.

So I've been thinking, is there a place which will be automatically called when a domain instance is load to generate the productRecord number?

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably leverage the [built-in Domain Events](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/#eventsAutoTimestamping):

> GORM supports the registration of events as methods that get fired
>   when certain events occurs such as deletes, inserts and updates. The
>   following is a list of supported events:
>
> - beforeInsert - Executed before an object is initially persisted to
>     the database
> - beforeUpdate - Executed before an object is updated
> - beforeDelete - Executed before an object is deleted
> - beforeValidate - Executed before an object is validated
> - afterInsert - Executed after an object is persisted to the database
> - afterUpdate - Executed after an object has been updated
> - afterDelete - Executed after an object has been deleted
> - onLoad - Executed when an object is loaded from the database

Have a look at the docs for some examples.

Comment: updated link: http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/#eventsAutoTimestamping

Answer (score 4):

Typically this is done by creating a read-only getter method and put the generation logic in there.  For example:

```
class Product { 
    String name, 
    String getProductRecord{ "Record " + id },

    static transients = ['productRecord']
}
```

Another example is available [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html).

Comment: agreed, just add a method to the domain class that computes the required value when called

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, this is also a good idea, but the onLoad event is what I am looking for, so I give the right answer to Rob this time. You definitely deserve a up vote.