# Grails - onSelect style GORM Method

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Does anyone know if there is anything in Grails similar to the beforeInsert or beforeUpdate gorm methods but for selects?

It would be useful for a use case we have to perform an action on certain domain attributes during selects

Comment: A few possibilities are outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453135/in-grails-is-there-something-in-domain-class-like-onload

Comment: thats will satisfy our case perfectly, thanks Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link provided by Andrew provides the solution we are after

Thanks again Andrew